# 407 response from proxy using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Below is the code that i used. I am using latest python [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests). I am getting `407` response from the below request using **python 2.7**.
And strange thing is i am getting 503 response while using `https` instead of `http` in the requests.

```
response = requests.get(query, proxies={'https': "https://username:password@104.247.XX.XX:80"}, headers=headers, timeout=30, allow_redirects=True)
print response
```

**Output: Response [503]**

```
response = requests.get(query, proxies={'http': "http://username:password@104.247.XX.XX:80"}, headers=headers, timeout=30, allow_redirects=True)
print response
```

**Output: Response [407]**

But the same code is working on my amazon ec2 instance. Though i am trying to run in local machine.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import portalocker
import cookielib
import requests

query = 'http://google.com/search?q=wtf&num=100&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2015&start=0&filter=0'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 Midori/0.4'}
response = requests.get(query, proxies={'http': "http://username:password@104.247.XX.XX:80"}, headers=headers, timeout=30, allow_redirects=True)
print response
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxyDict = { 
          'http'  : '77.75.105.165', 
          'https' : '77.75.105.165'
        }
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'mypassword')

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict, auth=auth)
```

Comment: Please see [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), posting code without explanation is not very useful

Answer (score -1):

The status codes might give a clue:

```
407 Proxy Authentication Required
503 Service Unavailable
```

These suggest that your proxy isn't running for https and the username/password combination is wrong for the proxy that you are using.  Note that it is very unlikely that your local machine needs the same proxy as your the ec2 instance.

Comment: Well, username and password combination is 100% correct.
i am getting 407 from http and 503 from https. I was getting 200 from https before.